# How to embed generic field using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa

Is it possible to embed generic field using Hibernate?

I tried to do this in a following way:

```
@Entity
public class Element<T> {

    @Embedded
    private T value;
...
```

But I've got:

```
 org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
 Property value has an unbound type and no explicit target entity.
```

I know that the target type of `value` will be a `SpecificValue` type. But how to specify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate cannot persist generic fields due to [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

However, I've managed to find a simple workaround:

1. Add `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` annotation to the class.
2. Add `@Transient` annotation to field you want to persist.
3. Create a **specific** getter and setter which uses this field.
4. Add `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` to the getter.
5. Make the type of the field embeddable by adding `@Embeddable` property to the class.

In this way you will be able to have an embedded property of specific type.

Here is a modified code:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Element<T> {

   @Transient
   private T value;

   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   private SpecificValue getValue() {
       return (SpecificValue) value;
   }

   private void setValue(SpecificValue v) {
       this.value = (T) v;
   }

...

@Embeddable
public class SpecificValue {

...
```